# Laravel: get all users with their days off on a specific month of a year

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have User and Holiday models related this way:

**User model:**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function holidays(): HasMany
    {
         return $this->hasMany(Holiday::class);
    }
```

**Holiday model:**

```php
class Holiday
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'dayoff', // DATE YYYY-MM-DD
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Given `$month` and `$year`, I would like to get all the users and their related holidays (`dayoff`).

How can I achieve that ?

**Edit:**

I re-wrote the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020788/3329664) this way:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$users = User::whereHas('holidays', function (Builder $query) use ($year, $month) {
    $query->whereYear('dayoff', $year)->whereMonth('dayoff', $month);
})->get();
```

But this gives the list of users without their related holidays (list of `dayoff`s of each user)

Comment: sorry, do you means you want collection of user that (for example) the `dayoff` is `2024` or `dayoff` is `April `  with the collection of `holidays` in `2024` or `April` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to get the list of users and the related holidays is

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$users = User::query()
    //this will filter the users depending on the condition of the relation
    ->whereHas('holidays', function (Builder $query) use ($year, $month) {
        $query->whereYear('dayoff', $year)->whereMonth('dayoff', $month);
    })
    //this will get the relation depending on the conditions
    ->with(['holidays' => function (Builder $query) use ($year, $month) {
        $query->whereYear('dayoff', $year)->whereMonth('dayoff', $month);
    }])
    ->get();
```

In the results you will have a collection of user models and in each one the attribute (relation) "holidays" containing a collection of the Holiday models that satisfy the condition.

One (`whereHas()`) is for filtering by the relation and the other (`with()`) is for getting the said relation

Comment: Very nice and clean :) I just got a small complaint about that `Builder`, I removed and it works. It grouped the holidays of every user automatically, as I wanted. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can use `left join` instead, so:

```
$month = $request->query('month');
$year = $request->query('year');

$users = User::leftJoin('holidays', function ($q) use ($month, $year) {
    $q->on('holidays.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->whereMonth('dayoff', '=', $month)
        ->whereYear('dayoff', '=', $year);
})->select('users.*', 'holidays.dayoff')
->whereNotNull('holidays.dayoff')->get();
```

Comment: just use `->groupBy('users.id')` before `->get()`

Comment: this: `$users = User::leftJoin('holidays', function ($q) use ($month, $year) {
    $q->on('holidays.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->whereMonth('dayoff', '=', $month)
        ->whereYear('dayoff', '=', $year);
})->select('users.*', 'holidays.dayoff')
->whereNotNull('holidays.dayoff')->groupBy('users.id')->get()`

Comment: no problem, but i can`t find any syntax error just add  ```;```  at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'whereHas'

```
$dayoff = Carbon::today();
User::whereHas('holidays', function ($q) use ($dayoff) {
            $q->where('dayoff', $dayoff);
        })->get();
```

Comment: your welcome, yes your code is better for your question. now you still have problem?

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve all users with their holidays for a specific month and year:

```
 // Assuming $month and $year are passed as query parameters
    $month = $request->query('month');
    $year = $request->query('year');

    // Retrieve all users with their holidays for the specified month and year
    $users = User::with(['holidays' => function ($query) use ($month, $year) {
        $query->whereMonth('dayoff', '=', $month)
              ->whereYear('dayoff', '=', $year);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Pure plagiarism of something I said it does not work

Comment: @BillalBegueradj I can't find the source. If you haven't already, please go to Flag -> choose Plagiarized content and post where the content originates and why you believe it to be plagiarised.

Comment: Copy/paste from my own question (edit section). Flagged @VLAZ

Comment: @BillalBegueradj I don't see anything copy/pasted. It's *similar* but clearly not *the same*. The order of method calls `->whereMonth('dayoff', '=', $month)->whereYear('dayoff', '=', $year);` is different, as are parameters passed into them. The `User::with` is different to your `User::whereHas` and your `'holidays', function (Builder $query) use ($year, $month)` is different to the associative array used in the answer. Moreover, I doubt the code in your question even counts as "original" given that you said you re-wrote it.

Comment: You are right about that `User::with`. But `>whereMonth('dayoff', '=', $month)`is the same as `>whereMonth('dayoff',  $month)` and he replaced `function (Builder $query)` from the answer provided by the other member (based on whom I edited my post). My post was edited several hours before this answer @VLAZ

Comment: @BillalBegueradj  what plagiarism,  please check my code and compare to yours.

Comment: @KwenziwaLizwiKhanyile the only difference you made is `User::with`.  The 2 other things you did are synonyms. It's like I say: "I go to school" and you say: "I walk to school". Besides, I wrote that this path is not something to explore